# Facebook database design...why have a profile table?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship, erd

See image below
[image]

Since 1 account has 1 profile relationship, Why have a profile table? what is the purpose of the profile table, apart from storing the status. Why not include status in the Account table and make a direct relationship from the "account" table to BasicInformation, PersonalInformation etc.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7GKB.jpg

Comment: Where did you get this structure?

Answer (score 3):

If, at some future time,  you change the model so that one account can have more than one profile, you are much better off with two tables than with just one.

With regard to the cost of joins,  you need to quantify that,  and decide where a speed difference just isn't worth worrying about.  Excessive fear of slowing things down with joins is one of the most common newbie mistakes with relational databases.

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas and educated guesses.

- At the conceptual level, an account
  and a profile are two different
  things.
- Adding the profile status to the
  account table makes that table wider
  and slower.
- Since status holds only your most
  recent post (is that right?), that
  table can be put on a separate
  tablespace, probably on an insanely
  fast disk array for fast lookups.
- Status is probably looked up much
  more often than anything in the
  account table.
- Security is simpler to administer.
  Lots of third-party apps might be
  allowed access to your status, but
  they shouldn't necessarily have
  access to your email address and
  password. Physical isolation (separate tables) is pretty easy to get obviously right.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's because not every Account will have a profile associated with it. i.e. the relationship is actually 1:0/1, not 1:1.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of abstraction.

An account has profile data in it. So, it has an instance (table) of a profile.

This way you can access profile data seperately, and maybe in the future add more data to the account.

Comment: You can still add more data to the account table without the profile table :)

Comment: Sure you CAN add. But this is a betetr abstraction. If you can name/group it, it can be a class/table. If you can call those fields "Profile information" then they can be grouped together as such.

Comment: You could probably do a huge table with lots of rows and coloumns to get all the relations in as well.

Comment: What's the point of it? It's all related data and there is always a related row. Don't you also lose performance by having to include joins in your queries?